# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ORDER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, circular-dependency

I am building the application in Agile Development with Rails using Rails 4.1.0.

I looked up forums regarding the issue: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ORDER and found that it was a possible error because of the rails version and so updated mt Gemfile to use Rails 4.0.0

I get the error on this Line:
     
     
       <%= f.label :pay_type %>
       **<%= f.text_field :pay_type, ORDER::PAYMENT_TYPE, prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>**
     
     
       <%= f.submit 'Place Order' %>

My Form is:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address, rows: 3, cols: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pay_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :pay_type, ORDER::PAYMENT_TYPE, prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Place Order' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My Order.rb is:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    PAYMENT_TYPE = ["Check", "Credit Card", "Purchase Order"]
end
```

I still get the error and am at my wits end to solving it since I have to submit this on Monday. :( :'(
 This is the full error stack trace. Can someone please help me!

```
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/ananyakaulgi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/ananyakaulgi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/ananyakaulgi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/ananyakaulgi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: `ORDER::PAYMENT_TYPE` should be `Order::PAYMENT_TYPE` - note that Order has a capitol O the rest is lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `ORDER::PAYMENT_TYPE`, it's `Order::PAYMENT_TYPE`.  Notice the case on `Order` class.  Using `ORDER` is going to raise `NameError`.

You also want to change the input helper used for `:pay_type` as `Order::PAYMENT_TYPE` returns an array.

```
<%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPE, include_blank: 'Select a payment method' %>
```

Also, you want to use the `include_blank` option instead of `prompt` for the "Select a payment method" text to appear as the default option.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Just a change in the CASE made so much of a difference!!! THANKS A LOT!!!